# How can I make an image a link when it already has an a href tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jQuery to make a row of tabs that are images. When you hover over the image it makes different things display.

However after talking to users many of them are trying to click on the images. I have tried adding another a href tag before the image but that breaks the hover effect.

Any ideas? Below is the existing code.

```
<li>
  <a href="#tabs-1"><img src=media/home/Sales.png id="circleleft"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#tabs-2"><img src=media/home/Integration.png id="circlecenterleft"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#tabs-3"><img src=media/home/Sales1.png id="circlecenterright"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#tabs-4"><img src=media/home/Blog.png id="circleright"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Where is your JS?

Comment: So why can't they click on the links that are in your post now?

Comment: The js is-  <script>
 jQuery( function() {
    jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      event: "mouseover"
    });
  } );
  </script>

Comment: Your ids are no longer just `#tabs` because they have the dash and number behind them.  Add a class to the hrefs and make the jquery target the class.

Comment: Those are just hover effects. the tabs isn't a link it makes different things display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite standard but if you wanted to you can add an `onClick` to your `<li>` which is the image wrapper then fire a function that redirects the page. Your `<a>` tag is still a better bet but this should work

```
<li onclick="myFunction()">Click me</li>

function myFunction() {
  location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org");
}
```

or the jQuery way

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```